# Problems with addclass and removeclass jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, addclass, removeclass

Im doing my first script for hide an iframe and show it with the jquery addclass and removeclass.
I have this, but i have some problems loading some iframes.

Can someone check for the js if it's correct?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#dvc-aut").click(function () {
        $(".dvc-aut").removeClass("dvc-pho dvc-spp dvc-spl dvc-tap dvc-tal");
    });
    $("#dvc-pho").click(function () {
        $(".dvc-aut").removeClass("dvc-spp dvc-spl dvc-tap dvc-tal").addClass("dvc-pho");
    });
    $("#dvc-spp").click(function () {
        $(".dvc-aut").removeClass("dvc-pho dvc-spl dvc-tap dvc-tal").addClass("dvc-spp");
    });
    $("#dvc-spl").click(function () {
        $(".dvc-aut").removeClass("dvc-pho dvc-spp dvc-tap dvc-tal").addClass("dvc-spl");
    });
    $("#dvc-tap").click(function () {
        $(".dvc-aut").removeClass("dvc-pho dvc-spp dvc-spl dvc-tal").addClass("dvc-tap");
    });
    $("#dvc-tal").click(function () {
        $(".dvc-aut").removeClass("dvc-pho dvc-spp dvc-spl dvc-tap").addClass("dvc-tal");
    });
});
```

```css
.div-dvc {
    border: 0px;
    display:inline;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
.btndvc {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:0px solid;
    width:35px;
    height:35px;
    background:#A4A4A4;
    z-index:2;
}
.dvc-table {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
.dvc-aut {
    display:none;
}
.dvc-pho {
    border-image-slice: 61 24 132 25;
    border-image-width: 61px 24px 132px 25px;
    border-image-outset: 59px 22px 130px 23px;
    border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
    border-image-source: url("http://i62.tinypic.com/2qddiwy.png");
    width:240px;
    height:320px;
    display:inherit;
}
.dvc-spp {
    border-image-slice: 122 21 125 22;
    border-image-width: 122px 21px 125px 22px;
    border-image-outset: 120px 19px 123px 20px;
    border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
    border-image-source: url("http://i62.tinypic.com/1zztlj.png");
    width:320px;
    height:480px;
    display:inherit;
}
.dvc-spl {
    border-image-slice: 21 122 22 125;
    border-image-width:21px 122px 22px 125px;
    border-image-outset: 19px 120px 20px 123px;
    border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
    border-image-source: url("http://i61.tinypic.com/2cxszrl.png");
    width:480px;
    height:320px;
    display:inherit;
}
.dvc-tap {
    border-image-slice: 114 96 114 96;
    border-image-width: 114px 96px 114px 96px;
    border-image-outset: 112px 94px 112px 94px;
    border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
    border-image-source: url("http://i58.tinypic.com/fwq4bl.png");
    width:767px;
    height:1024px;
    display:inherit;
}
.dvc-tal {
    border-image-slice: 96 114 96 114;
    border-image-width: 96px 114px 96px 114px;
    border-image-outset: 94px 112px 94px 112px;
    border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
    border-image-source: url("http://i62.tinypic.com/2nc2ag9.png");
    width:1024px;
    height:767px;
    display:inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></script>

<div class="div-dvc">
    <button id="dvc-aut" class="btndvc fa fa-desktop" title="Auto"></button>
    <button id="dvc-pho" class="btndvc fa fa-mobile " title="Old Phone"></button>
    <button id="dvc-spp" class="btndvc fa fa-mobile-phone fa-lg" title="Smartphone Portrait"></button>
    <button id="dvc-spl" class="btndvc fa fa-mobile-phone fa-rotate-90 fa-lg" title="Smartphone Landscape"></button>
    <button id="dvc-tap" class="btndvc fa fa-tablet fa-lg" title="Tablet Portrait"></button>
    <button id="dvc-tal" class="btndvc fa fa-tablet fa-rotate-90 fa-lg" title="Tablet Landscape"></button>
</div>
<br>
<table class="dvc-table">
    <td>
        <p align="center">
            <iframe class="dvc-aut" src="test.html" />
        </p>
    </td>
</table>
```

```
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AbeAlpha/fpmzf1nx/
```

Or maybe somthing on the html?
Im using same id and class names, i try to change but still not work.
Im rly a bit lost

I try to paste in other online editors like codepen or kodtest and nothing works. Im a bit sad

Comment: Show us what you have done so far

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbeAlpha/fpmzf1nx/)

Comment: It seems there is something wrong with your css. If you remove it things work better. So have a look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with what you have at the moment.
Firstly you have a container taking up the full display, over the top of them:

```
.dvc-table {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
```

You can fix this by putting the buttons above the iframe wrapper: 
`.div-dvc {z-index: 2;}`

Secondly, you hide the iframe with

```
.dvc-aut {
    display:none;
}
```

But you never show it again. Just remove this, or add a show() to one of your buttons. [Here's a fiddle with working buttons](http://jsfiddle.net/1a3hj6jd/).

Comment: The first button is just for hide the iframe when u push any other button, the other butons are for see the iframe in diferents sizes.
For defaut i wana hide the iframe if i do not push any button

Comment: In that case it's just the first part of the problem.. as long as the buttons arent beneath your wrapper, it should work. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1a3hj6jd/

Comment: Now i see chrome do not work, only firefox :S

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Many thanks for the triks :) i stand a bit.
My question now is any way to do not load the iframe till i push a button?
the idea for this script is for do somthing like --> [link](http://www.joomlart.com/demo/#ja_jason) in the top right but i only wana load the same webpage in a diferent size on iframe. This is for testing and do not need to drag the browser for resizing. 
For this i wana load only sometimes this iframe, not allways.

Comment: My idea is to have the webpage, and if i push, then have 2 same webpages, but the iframe in front, think with a background at 50% dark transparent or somthing like that.
Don't wana have the root webpage on a iframe

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/mvdLg44t/1/

Comment: :D wow looks rly beauty ;D more than JA wana study a bit this effects :d
but the problem still that if u dont load the iframe at start then is not working correct, ur first examle loads nice the iframe, the second inside the iframe are some bugs. Can be the iframe fixed at the page centred horizontal and vertical automatly?

Comment: Wops this last example is working perfect with chrome!!!, but firefox is rendering the iframe problems :S

Comment: I did suscce swith: $("#dvcframe").attr("src", src = dvciframe); Now the problem is that everey time i push a button hte iframe take refresh :/
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/AbeAlpha/ccce9y3j/)